# How to create indexes on tables efficiently. Can I create index on date

Tags: postgresql

I need to create an index on table in Postgresql. Table contains columns (pk_id,doc_no,date). I will use date in WHERE clause. Is there any need to create index on date for better performance? This table structure is only a model. Actual table contains 65 columns and more than 100k rows.

Comment: "*Can you create an index on a `date` column?*" - yes, absolutely. "*Is there a need to create an index for better performance?*" - depends on the query you are using. Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: Write a query, use EXPLAIN ANALYZE on it. Generally where you see 'seq scan ' and 'filter' these could be better performing with index usage. Even a table of 100,000 rows can be made to perform much faster than and unindexed version.